# Ubuntu doesn't detect android hotspot

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect to my android from Ubuntu 13.04 PC.
But my wireless manager in ubuntu can't detect my android wireless network.
I tried on windows and it works , what could be the problem ?
Also : usb tethering works in ubuntu just the wireless doesn't.
Additional Info:
1 - my friends ubuntu (same as mine) detects my phone.
2 - my ubuntu detects my friends android hotspot.

It looks like the problem is my ubuntu.
Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your access point could be too close to your box (think you have it tethered and on a 2 foot cable).  I have a mobile hotspot that routinely doesn't join unless I lay the cable as straight as possible to get it further from my lappie.

Comment: there is no cable involved , just turned "enable wifi tether" in android

Comment: Then move it further away.  I find about 4 feet gets things working and less is a sometimes, sometimes not.